# A propriedade stack não é removida do objecto Error quando includeStack é igual a false

Tags: node.js, loopback

A propriedade stack não é removida do objecto Error quando includeStack é igual a `false`:

```
"final:after": {
    "loopback#errorHandler": {
        "params": {
            "includeStack": false
        }
    }
}
```

Mesmo com o disableStackTrace igual a `true` no config.json:

```
"errorHandler": {
    "disableStackTrace": true
}
```

O que estou a fazer errado?

O `errorHandler` apenas serve para erros 404?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta? O que é `loopback`, o código que gerou esse erro, um exemplo live no https://c9.io/ ou algo que nos ajude a perceber o teu problema...

Comment: @Sergio loopback é uma framework para gerar API Rest com nodejs. Mais informações aqui: http://loopback.io/. Os termos que usei são todos usados na framework, pode parecer que a pergunta está incompleta mas não está.

Comment: Ok, dei  `+1`. Se tiver tempo daqui a pouco vou dar uma olhada a ver se posso ajudar. Entretanto se tiveres um minuto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/3708

Comment: @Sergio vou adicionar mais informações sobre a tag assim que chegar a casa.

Comment: Conseguiste resolver o problema?

Comment: @Sergio Sim, vou postar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

A configuração de erros no Loopback é feita através de 2 ficheiros: config.json e middleware.json.

A inclusão do stack (descrição detalhada do erro) no Loopback funciona da seguinte maneira:

O arquivo **server/config.json**:

1. Apenas para erros do tipo 500.
2. Funciona apenas se a variável de ambiente `NODE_ENV` for diferente de "production", uma vez que para produção o stack é removido (o que faz todo sentido).
3. Para desativar o stack em outros ambientes, basta editar a propriedade `errorHandler`:

```
"errorHandler": {
    "disableStackTrace": true
}
```

O arquivo **server/middleware.json** para outros tipos de erros:

1. Desativa/Ativa em qualquer ambiente, incluindo o de produção uma vez que não são desativados automaticamente como ocorre com os erros do tipo 500.
2. Para desativar os erros, basta adicionar a seguinte propriedade:

```
"final:after": {
    "loopback#errorHandler": {
        "params": {
            "includeStack": false
        }
    }
}
```

Para separar as configurações de cada ambiente, basta criar os arquivos com o nome do respectivo ambiente, por exemplo, um projeto com 2 ambientes: developer e production.

Basta criar o `middleware.production.json` e `config.production.json` que quando a variável de ambiente `NODE_ENV` for igual a `production`, automaticamente o Loopback irá carregar o arquivo de configurações correto.

Comment: Ainda sou iniciante em Loopback então não vou escolher a minha própria resposta como certa para não induzir ninguém a erros, mas até agora funcionou e não encontrei nada que indicasse o contrário.